# Symbolic link not working

Tags: directory, symbolic-link, paths, hard-link

I tried to make a symbolic link between directories, but it's not working.  I made a directory called C_drive and then did the following command:

`sudo ln -s this/directory/way/over/here/myfolder ~/other/directory/C_drive`

and it seemed to work, i.e. my C_drive folder has two things in it - 'myfolder' in red and 'John' ('John' is my name, and it is the name of a directory on the path to /other/directory/C_drive, but it is not capitalized there) in cyan.  a cyan is supposed to be a symbolic link and red is supposed to be an archive link? I have no idea why 'John' appears in this directory as the symbolic link when I made no such instruction.  More importantly, when I try to cd into **either one** of these, it says 'no such file or directory'.

All I want to do is create a shared folder at C_drive - that is, a folder where if I add, delete or alter files, the exact same thing happens at the other location.  I've read dozens of help pages, and I still can't figure it out.

Comment: Perhaps you can do an `ls -l` at both locations and update your question with the output?  If the symbolic link is successful, it will indicate so.  I wouldn't rely on colours because one can change the default colours (I think; I've never tried myself).  Also, I wouldn't suggest you use `sudo`.  If you have permissions for both directories, you can do the `ln` as yourself.

Comment: Thanks!  Your solution revealed that it was just a syntax error.  I had a two-name folder name that needed to be written 'Firstname Lastname' with the single quotes.

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad it worked out for you!